# Why isn't Legendre's Conjecture resolved by the work done by Nair and Hanson in relation to Least Common Multiples?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, fake-proofs, least-common-multiple

I recently discovered the work done by Hanson and Nair.  As I worked through Hanson's proof, an argument occurred to me regarding [Legendre's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture).

Clearly, my argument is wrong.  It is too simple not to have been discovered in the time that these proofs have been available.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me understand where my reasoning is wrong.

(1) Nair [proved](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.3401.pdf):

> For any $n \in N^*$, we have:
>   $$\text{lcm}({n\choose 1},2{n\choose 2},\dots,n{n\choose n})=\text{lcm}(1,2,\dots,n)$$

(2) So it follows:

$$\text{lcm}(1,2,\dots,(n^2+n)) > \left(\frac{n^2+n}{2}\right){{n^2+n}\choose{\frac{n^2+n}{2}}}$$

(3) It is straight forward to show for $n \ge 4$

> $${{2n}\choose n} > \frac{4^n}{n}$$

(4) So it follows:

$$\text{lcm}(1,2,\dots,(n^2+n)) > \left(\frac{n^2+n}{2}\right)\frac{4^{n^2+n}}{n^2+n} = \frac{4^{n^2+n}}{2}$$

(5) Hanson [proved](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267137759_On_the_product_of_the_primes):

> Let $B(n)$ denote the least common multiple of the integers $1,\dots,n$. Then 
>   $$B(n) < 3^n$$

(6) So, it follows:

$$\text{lcm}(1,2,\dots,n^2) < 3^{n^2}$$

(7) Let $R(x,y) = \dfrac{\text{lcm}(1,2,\dots,x)}{\text{lcm}(1,2,\dots,y)}$

(7) So that:

$$R(n^2+n,n^2) > \frac{\frac{4^{n^2+n}}{2}}{3^{n^2}}=\frac{4^n}{2}\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^{n^2} > 4^n$$

(8) Assume that there is no prime between $n^2$ and $n^2+n$.

(9) So, the value of $R(n^2+n,n^2)$ must be equal to the product of the relative powers of primes $p^a$ such that $n^2 < p^a \le n^2+n$.

> Note: I say "relative" since for $a \ge 2$, $R(p^a,p^a-1) = p$

(10) If $p$ is a prime such that $n^2 < p^a \le (n^2+n)$, it follows that $p \le \lfloor\sqrt{n^2+n}\rfloor = n$

(11) If $n^2 < p^a \le (n^2+n)$, then $p^{a+1} = p(p^a) > pn^2$

(12) It is well known that $\prod\limits_{p \le n} p < 4^n$ where $p$ is a prime.

(13) So that, $R(n^2+n,n^2) < 4^{\pi(n)}$ where $\pi(n)$ is the [prime counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function).

(14) It is well known for $n\ge8$ that $\pi(n) \le \frac{n}{2}$

(15) But then we have a contradiction since:

$$R(n^2+n,n^2) \le 4^{n/2}$$

(16) So, we reject our assumption that there is no prime between $n^2$ and $n^2+n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> (4) So it follows:$$\text{lcm}(1,2,\dots,(n^2+n)) > \left(\frac{n^2+n}{2}\right)\frac{4^{n^2+n}}{n^2+n} = \frac{4^{n^2+n}}{2}$$

This is incorrect. It should be
$$\text{lcm}(1,2,\dots,(n^2+n)) > \left(\frac{n^2+n}{2}\right)\frac{4^{(n^2+n)/2}}{(n^2+n)/2}=4^{(n^2+n)/2}$$

Comment: Thanks very much.  That's right.  That was the mistake.